# Forum MySQL Category, Thread, Post

Tags: mysql, multithreading, forum, categories, posts

I know there's a bunch of threads similar to this and I looked over many, but was unable to find a solution.  So, I have one table called "forum" that houses my Categories (num_type=0), Threads (num_type=1), and Posts (num_type=2).  There is a column num_parent that will relate the Thread/Post to the parent Category/Thread.  With the query that I am having issues with, I am trying to get all of the Categories, the total Threads inside of each Category, and the total Posts inside the Threads of each Category.  To do this, I am trying:

```
select F.*
, count(F2.num_Forum) as num_ThreadCount
, count(F3.num_Forum) as num_PostCount
, max(F3.dte_Created) as dte_LastPost
from forum F
left outer join forum F2
on F.num_Forum=F2.num_Parent and F2.num_Type=1
left outer join forum F3
on F2.num_Forum=F3.num_Parent and F3.num_Type=2
where F.num_Type=0 and F.num_Inactive=0
group by F.num_Forum
order by F.num_Sticky desc, F.dte_Created desc
```

The dte_LastPost and num_PostCount are coming out correctly.  The num_ThreadCount is not.  If I break up the query into two seperate queries:

```
select F.* 
, count(F2.num_Forum) as num_ThreadCount
from forum F
left outer join forum F2
on F.num_Forum=F2.num_Parent and F2.num_Type=1
where F.num_Type=0 and F.num_Inactive=0
group by F.num_Forum
order by F.num_Sticky desc, F.dte_Created desc

select count(F3.num_Forum) as num_PostCount
from forum F2
left outer join forum F3
on F2.num_Forum=F3.num_Parent and F3.num_Type=2
where F2.num_Type=1 and F2.num_Inactive=0
group by F2.num_Forum
order by F2.num_Sticky desc, F2.dte_Created desc
```

I am getting the correct count for each.  But, I need to combine these somehow so that I know which Category the num_PostCount corresponds to.  The big difference that I see with doing it separately is that in the second query, I am able to do group by F2.num_Forum.  I tried adding it to the conglomerate query, but it did not fix my issue.  Anyone know what I need to do to fix my first query?

Comment: Sounds to me like you should redesign your database.  A thread is not a forum, and a post is not a thread nor is it a forum.  Sounds like you're cramming too much in one table.

Comment: I appreciate your input, but I did think about the design for a while and it is the way I would like it to be.  I first thought about breaking it up into three tables, but soon realized that the columns were all redundant and the only difference would have been the name of the tables.

Comment: @Corbin is right...your approach is all wrong.  Just because all 3 of the tables might have the same structure in terms of columns and data type , doesn't mean they're redundant.  You're talking about 3 distinctly different pieces of data - Forum, Post & Thread, each properly belonging in their own tables. Any further querying/searching against your design will become unnecessarily complicated and prone to errors.

Comment: Ok, so let's say that I do break it up into three tables.  I may end up doing this in case I later want to add attributes to only the threads or whatever.  But, that does not resolve my issue.  To get the information that I need, I will still need to do a query almost exactly like this, only instead of querying itself, I'll be querying Threads for F2 and Posts for F3.  But, the thread count will still be incorrect as it is in this query.  What am I doing wrong in the query?

Comment: What I may just do is add a column to the Posts table that links to the Categories table as a parent ID.  That way, I do not need to go through the Threads table to figure out which Posts belong to which Categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to figure out the query to link the three tables WITHOUT putting a column in the Posts table to link it directly to the Category.  Instead, Categories links to Threads which links to Posts, down and up the chain.

```
select C.*
, count(TP.num_Thread) as num_ThreadCount
, coalesce(sum(TP.num_PostCount), 0) as num_PostCount
from forum_categories C 
left join 
(select count(P.num_Post) as num_PostCount, 
T.num_Thread, T.num_CParent, T.num_Inactive
from forum_threads T
left outer join forum_posts P
on P.num_TParent=T.num_Thread and P.num_Inactive=0
where T.num_Inactive=0
group by T.num_Thread) TP 
on C.num_Category=TP.num_CParent and TP.num_Inactive=0
where C.num_Inactive=0
group by C.num_Category
order by C.num_Sticky desc, C.dte_Created desc
```